# Populate table with jquery/json

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, jquery

I have an asp.net web page and I want to populate the table with jquery, ajax web service call something. But I am not strong on it at all.
The html part for the table is:

```
<tbody id="testBody">
            <tr id="templateEquipment" class="hidden">
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

I already defined the columns and the table is empty at the beginning. And in jquery

```
function SearchEquipment() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: pageName + "SearchEquipment",
    data: "{'oParams':" + JSON.stringify(BeginSearch()) + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.d.length > 0) {

            $.each(response.d, function (i, item) {
            <!-- add row to fill the table-->
```

Thanks for your help. I do not have the resources for that(links are welcomed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
var html = $.map(response.d, function (item, i) {
  return "<tr><td>" + item.value1 + "</td><td>" + item.value2 + "</td></tr>";
}).join("");

$("#testbody").append(html);
```

By creating a big string with all the rows and cells in it you only need to add it once to the DOM which is a lot quicker!

Comment: @Love Not sure what you mean. If you refresh the page everything is gone and you need to repopulate the table again (if you want). You can clear the table by doing $("#testbody").empty();